# Is it possible to simulate/test a 'moving' iPhone with Xamarin Studio and the iPhone Emulator?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xcode, xamarin

Given the standard iOS Map that comes with XCode/Xamarin Studio when creating a simple iPhone application, is there an easy way to do:

given a list of lat/longs, read in this list every x seconds and plot it to the map.

I know how to plot the current location to a map.

I also have the following code which I'm trying to test - this I believe is wired up so when a new location has been 'discovered', it will re-plot it to the screen.

```
map.DidUpdateUserLocation += (sender, e) => {
    if (map.UserLocation != null) 
    {
        CentreMapAtLocation(map.UserLocation.Coordinate.Latitude,
                            map.UserLocation.Coordinate.Longitude);
    }
```

Is there some trick, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Xamarin before, but the iOS Simulator is capable of testing locations, if you click `Debug->Location`. From here you can either use a custom location (which simulates the device being at that location) or something like `Freeway Drive`, which simulates a device traveling.

I'm also assuming that the reading of the list of coordinates is something for testing. If so, the Xcode debugger console can read the coordinates from `GPX` files by clicking on the grey navigation arrow icon. [This is a good reference](http://blackpixel.com/blog/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html) to help you get started. I'm not sure if Xamarin has similar functionality.